# Dynamics365 : Stop Products from Copying when Quote is Created

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

I am developing plugins in Microsoft Dynamics365 CRM and I need **Opportunity Products NOT** to get copied when one creates a new quote. I want to manually do that with a plugin, so as to perform certain calculations and set custom fields.

How do I disable this out of box feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you can stop the OOB behavior because of the nature of Sales pipeline (Opportunity products cloned to Quote details on Quote creation).

But anyway you are planning to re-add those products using plugin (guess it is going to be Asynchronous Post Create on Quote). In that plugin, you can delete the cloned products (quote detail) which came from Oppty before re-adding into Quote.

Comment: You sir, have just saved me! I had implemented that exact solution, but my implementation was flawed because my plugin was Synchronous! Changing it to Asynchronous allowed me to delete those cloned products! Hats off to you!